# Python subprocess.run does not work when called from the same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose following directory structure with two simple scripts

```
dir/
├── main.py
└── sub_routine.py
```

main.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import run
from pathlib import Path

my_dir = Path(__file__).parent
run([my_dir / "sub_routine.py"])
```

sub_routine.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("Hello there!")
```

When I run `main.py` from ancestor directory of `dir` it works properly:

```
~$ python3 ./dir/main.py
Hello there!
```

However, when I run it **from** `dir` it fails:

```
~$ cd dir
~/dir$ python3 ./main.py
...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: PosixPath('sub_routine.py'): PosixPath('sub_routine.py')
```

Why? And how can I ensure this will work regardless of where it's called from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that pathlib strips any leading `./` from your path, which results in `sub_routine.py` instead of `./sub_routine.py`. Subprocess therefore searches for an executable in your $PATH, which it of course cannot find. If there is a directory before it, say `dir/sub_routine.py`, it recognizes it as a path relative to your current directory and therefore works as expected.

The easiest solution is probably to use pathlib to convert the path to an absolute one: `(my_dir / "sub_routine.py").absolute()`

Answer (score 0):

I would use this: (or Lukors answer)

```
path = Path(__file__)
print(str(path.parent.absolute()) + "/" + "sub_routine.py")
```

Or with os.path:

```
path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
print(os.path.dirname(path))
```

Comment: you should really leave concatenating paths to pathlib, and only convert to string afterwards